# Validate a single field in Complex Type Model in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-validation

I have a Complex Model like this

```
    public class MyModel
     {
       [ValidateComplexType]
       public Student Student { get; set; } = new Student();
     }

   public class Student
     {
      [Required]
      public string Name { get; set; }
      [Required]
      public string Subject { get; set; }
     }
```

and my blazor code is like this

```
    <EditForm Model="this.Model" OnValidSubmit="Submit" @ref="this.myEditForm">
      <ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator />
        <div class="form-group row">
         <label for="name" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
         <div class="col-md-10">
          <InputText id="name" class="form-control" @bind-Value="this.Model.Student.Name" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => this.Model.Student.Name)" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="supplier" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Subject</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <InputText id="supplier" class="form-control" @bind-Value="this.Model.Student.Subject" />
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => this.Model.Student.Subject)" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @onclick="Validate">Validate</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    @code 
      {
private MyModel Model { get; set; } = new MyModel();
private EditForm myEditForm { get; set; }

   private void Validate()
    {    
     this.myEditForm.EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(
     this.myEditForm.EditContext.Field(nameof(this.Model.Student.Name)));
     }

     private void Submit()
      {

      }
    }
```

I want validate a single field on Validate button click. If my model is non complex type, above code works fine. Since this is a complex type, above code is not working. Is i am doing any thing wrong here?

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? Any exception? Unexpected results? What is your input-data, what do you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: Anyway: why should validation fire a FieldChange-event?

Comment: Use OnSubmit to take control of validation fields

Comment: @HimBromBeere i want to perform some action based on particular field. so i have to validate that field

Comment: @NicolaBiada  if i submit, this will validate all my fields. I want to validate a single field

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to valid a field that you've never updated.  On single field validation it looks like `ObjectGraphDataAnnotationsValidator` is checking if the field has an entry in the Fields collection in `EditContext` to verify that some form of modification has taken place i.e. trying to be clever!.  If you want what your trying to do then consider using a different validator.  There are far better ones out there.  Search *Blazor Validation Controls*.  Amongst others there one by Blazorize and one I've written (and you can get the source code for and modify).